# How much information about a family is contained in its closed fibres?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, flatness

One general type of question I am unsure how to approach is "how much information can we deduce about a family given information about its closed fibres?" As a concrete example, say we have a projective variety $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and a family of coherent sheaf homomorphisms $\varphi:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ on $X$ parameterised by some connected $S$. Let's say we know these sheaves are well-behaved (for example, they have constant $h^0$'s), and let's say we know that at every closed $s\in S$ the fibre $\varphi_s: \mathcal{F}_s\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_s$ is an isomorphism; could we deduce that $\varphi$ itself is an isomorphism? Or what about if we know $H^0(\varphi_s): H^0(\mathcal{F}_s) \rightarrow H^0(\mathcal{G}_s)$ is an isomorphism, could we deduce $H^0(\varphi)$ is itself an isomorphism?

Comment: I don't understand the relation of $X$, $S$, and the sheaves. Please, be more precise.

Comment: $X$ is just a projective variety, and $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are just flat families of sheaves on $X$ parameterised by some scheme $S$ (so i.e. they are sheaves on $X\times S$ flat over $S$). I'm just wondering eg. if we know every closed fibre of the map $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, can we deduce $\varphi$ itself is an isomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

If $\varphi \colon \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}$ is a morphism of coherent sheaves on $X \times S$ such that $\varphi_s \colon \mathcal{F}_s \to \mathcal{G}_s$ is an isomorphism for every closed $s \in S$, then indeed $\varphi$ is an isomorphism. Assume also that $\mathcal{G}$ is flat over $S$.

First, let $\mathcal{C}$ be the cokernel of $\varphi$. Then for every closed $s$ we have an exact sequence
$$
\mathcal{F}_s \to \mathcal{G}_s \to \mathcal{C}_s \to 0
$$
(because the restriction functor is right exact). Your assumption implies $\mathcal{C}_s = 0$ for each $s$, and since $\mathcal{C}$ is coherent, it follows that $\mathcal{C} = 0$, so that $\varphi$ is surjective.

Now let $\mathcal{K}$ be the kernel of $\varphi$. Using flatness of $\mathcal{G}$ we obtain an exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathcal{K}_s \to \mathcal{F}_s \to \mathcal{G}_s \to 0
$$
and again your assumption imples $\mathcal{K}_s = 0$, hence $\mathcal{K} = 0$, because it is coherent. Thus, $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Perhaps this wasn't reflected in my question correctly, but I'm wondering if there's a "general" methodology for deducing properties about a family of sheaves from properties of closed fibres? So e.g. if $\mathscr{P}$ is some property enjoyed by certain sheaves, and if we know every closed fibre  $\mathcal{F}_s$ of a family $\mathcal{F}$ has property $\mathscr{P}$ then is there a general tool for showing that $\mathcal{F}$ has that property too? Or is that too general to answer?

Comment: I think this question is indeed too general.